# Change specific array values to uppercase

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with the following key/values:

FirstName, LastName, EmployeeNumber, Location

I need to convert the values contained in FirstName and LastName to all UPPERCASE.

I have tried using

```
array_map('strtoupper', $myARR);
```

But I get this error:

```
Warning: strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
```

I think it is because employee number is numeric, so it errors out because a numeric is not a string? I do not know what else I can try, to attempt this. The reason being is that I have combined two arrays into one. One of the arrays coming from a DB is in all UPPER, while the other is not. This causes me to be unable to sort the array properly, as it does not see BROWN and Brown as the same value. 
If I sort these five names:

```
BATMAN CHARLES BYRON Carl Bill
```

The result is this

```
BATMAN
BYRON
Bill
CHARLES
Carl
```

If I can get the ucfirst values to be all UPPER then the sort will work correctly (as one value from the table that has ucfirst only, is a 2 letter nickname (AJ) and it sorts correctly with the other data that is all UPPER).

Any ideas on how I can get the values to be UPPER for just those two portions of the array? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is some data pulled from the array:

**Portion of Array with First Letter Capitalized**

```
[59] => Array ( 
    [0] => First 
    [1] => Last 
    [2] => 123456 
    [3] => Location )
```

**Portion of Array with All Letter Capitalized**

```
[1116] => Array ( 
      [0] => FIRST
      [1] => LAST
      [2] => 123456
      [3] => Location )
```

I cannot put the actual values here on the website, but essentially the values change for all people in the array. But at least this should show how each element in the array looks as far as uppercase values and what not.

Comment: Yeah I will post an example of some code. Give me a few, as I have to change the actual data (not allowed to post actual values, per company policy).

Comment: Is this a simple array, or a 2d array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($employees as $e) {
  $e['firstName'] = strtoupper($e['firstName']);
  ... same for lastName
}
```

Comment: I was messing with your provided solution, which was working great, but for some reason the search function I am using didn't like it. It did give me an idea though, what I did was to do a strtoupper($OriginalLDAPArray) before I created the new combined array and it worked!! Which I didn't know you could do.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to parsing all to upper case.. You could just use a case-insensitive sorting function: [natcasesort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php)

$sorted = natcasesort($myARR)

Comment: I tried that, but I found a sorting function on here, and it does not seem to work with natcasesort =/

Answer (score 0):

a simple way would be

```
$Capsfield = strtoupper($youarray['yourfeild']);
```

but that would not be recrusive, @Just Somebody gave a better thinking...